# Как вычислить корень любой заданной степени из числа, не используя функцию Math::pow?

Tags: dart, любой-язык

Как можно вычислить корень любой заданной степени из числа, не используя функцию `Math::pow`?

```
void res() {
    int root = 2, numb = 16;
    num res = pow(numb, 1 / root);

    print(res); //Output: 4.0
  }
```

Возможно есть решения на других ЯП, тоже ознакомлюсь с ответами.

Comment: С чем связан запрет на использование Math::pow ?

Comment: @Kromster , условие задачи: вычислить корень любой заданной степени из числа, не используя math::pow

Comment: Учебное задание?

Comment: @Kromster , всё верно, в рамках онлайн-курса.

Comment: Это полное условие, или есть ограничения на целочисленность степени или что-то подобное?

Comment: Для начала - https://habr.com/ru/post/469735/

Comment: @Kromster, вообще это условие и + реализовать метод как extension-метод для num.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141075/discussion-between-bahmn-and-kromster).

Comment: Степень вычисляется через экспоненту. Экспонента дозволена?

Comment: @MBo , про это ничего не сказано. Значит дозволена.

Comment: Тогда воспользуйтесь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ заложен в данной статье [Алгоритм вычисления корня n-ой степени из произвольного положительного числа](https://habr.com/ru/post/469735/)

```
double mabs(double x) {
  return (x < 0) ? -x : x;
}

class RootNumber {
  void res() {
    double num = 521;
    int rootDegree = 11;

    double eps = 0.0001;
    double root = num / rootDegree;
    double rn = num;
    while (mabs(root - rn) >= eps) {
      rn = num;
      for (int i = 1; i < rootDegree; i++) {
        rn = rn / root;
      }
      root = 0.5 * (rn + root);
    }
    print('Result = ${root.toStringAsFixed(3)}');
  }
}
```

Comment: т.е. Т.е. это проще показалось, чем в моём ответе?

Comment: куратору предоставил 2 ответа. оказалось по условию либу Math вообще нельзя было использовать.

Comment: Вот как... Ясно.

Answer (score 1):

```
res = exp(ln(numb) / root);
```

Всё.